# Easy Admin указать уникальность поля

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

здесь https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/1923
указано что можно использовать

EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Mapping\Annotation

но у меня нет такого класса.

"easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^2.1",

Comment: Вы с этим человеком в одном чате телеги общаетесь, не проще ли задать ему вопрос напрямую? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно корректно указать в Entity что используется в yaml конфиге сущности

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SomeRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("some-title")
 */
class Some
{
```

где Some - Entity, а some-title - уникальное поле